# MySql InnoDB table Updating single row takes 1+ second

Tags: mysql

I've checked many answers but didn't get exact solution. I'm trying to update single row of User table having 50k~ records.

DB Engine: InnoDB

```
id - varchar(45) (Primary key + Unique Key)
notificationToken - small text
```

The reason primary key datatype varchar is our login integrated with firebase. so app sending this id.

I'm performing below query.

```
UPDATE User 
    SET notificationToken = 'notification token' 
WHERE id = 'my string id';
```

This query tooks 1+ second sometimes and mostly 0.800ms

Even i've tried by creating new auto_increment column + index but still query response time is same.

Comment: Did you try adding an index on the `notificationToken` column

Comment: No not at the moment.. but what if we have some other fields to update. we can't assign index to all other fields. anyway let me give a try.

Comment: You add indexes to columns that you use to access a row, not all columns.

Comment: I've tried but still response time is same.

Comment: what is explain telling you?

Comment: id=1, select_type=UPDATE,table=User,partitions=NULL,type=range,possible_keys='PRIMARY,id',key=PRIMARY,key_len=182,ref=const,rows=1,filtered=100.00,Extra=Using Where

Comment: Explain says its uses primary key on id field. but it not consistence. i think there is some ongoing maintenance on cloud sql by google team.